# SyntaxError: 'await' outside function - Error in local script, works in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

This works in Jupyter notebooks but gives a `SyntaxError: 'await' outside function` in a local python script.  I've imported all of the same python modules in the Jupiter notebook.

```
async def download(url, filename):
    response = await pyfetch(url)
    if response.status == 200:
        with open(filename, "wb") as f: # write binary mode
            f.write(await response.bytes())


path='https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-ML0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Module%204/data/Cust_Segmentation.csv' 

# download(path, "Cust_Segmentation.csv") # Produces this error: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'download' was never awaited
await download(path, "Cust_Segmentation.csv")
```

and got this error

```
    await download(path, "Cust_Segmentation.csv")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
```

Any idea what's going on?  Remember, this works in Jupyter notebooks and NOT in

**Solutions Attempted**

I tried removing the `await` before calling the function and got this error: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'download' was never awaited`.

The following links do not appear to be relevant.

- [%time await main() throws SyntaxError: 'await' outside function in jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231636/time-await-main-throws-syntaxerror-await-outside-function-in-jupyter)
- [discord.py SyntaxError: 'await' outside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870827/discord-py-syntaxerror-await-outside-function)

This may have some relevance, but I've tried removing the await and it still throws a different error: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'download' was never awaited` or `UnboundLocalError: local variable '_jsfetch' referenced before assignment`

- ['await' outside function error given when running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67203632/await-outside-function-error-given-when-running-program)

Specific error with `asyncio.run(download(URL, "Cust_Segmentation.csv"))` is the following:

```
tail example.py

filename ="Cust_Segmentation.csv"

async def download(url, filename):
    response = await pyfetch(url)
    if response.status == 200:
        with open(filename, "wb") as f: # write binary mode
            f.write(await response.bytes())

asyncio.run(download(URL, "Cust_Segmentation.csv"))
```

Produces:

```
python3 example.py
/data/XXX/miniconda/envs/devel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py:146: UserWarning: A NumPy version >=1.16.5 and <1.23.0 is required for this version of SciPy (detected version 1.23.1
  warnings.warn(f"A NumPy version >={np_minversion} and <{np_maxversion}"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/DEMO/MachineLearning/k-means_clustering/example.py", line 33, in <module>
    asyncio.run(download(URL, "Cust_Segmentation.csv"))
  File "/data/XXX/miniconda/envs/devel/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/data/XXX/miniconda/envs/devel/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/mnt/d/DEMO/MachineLearning/k-means_clustering/example.py", line 28, in download
    response = await pyfetch(url)
  File "/data/XXX/miniconda/envs/devel/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodide/http.py", line 234, in pyfetch
    url, await _jsfetch(url, to_js(kwargs, dict_converter=Object.fromEntries))
UnboundLocalError: local variable '_jsfetch' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: The last link seems to be relevant. `asyncio.run(download(path, "Cust_Segmentation.csv"))`

Comment: That gets `UnboundLocalError: local variable '_jsfetch' referenced before assignment`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be related to this code.

Comment: See original post, I put in an addendum.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That seems to be a bug in the library, I'm not sure how it can be caused by the way you're calling it.

Comment: Try the requests library instead https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/